# JOOQ: Get table and columns with string?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

Hello I'm using JOOQ with Spring Boot and was wondering if there was a way to obtain a table and its columns with a string of their name? For example:

I want to be able to get a table by doing something like:

`someObject.getTable("user")`

Then using the result of that get method I also want to obtain all of that table's columns and be able to compare the column names to other strings. In other words if there is a way to get a table, can I also get the table's column names from that same object?

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can:

#### Using the code generator

When you generate your schema, all this information is available to you from generated code. Just go to your schema and look for the table (case-sensitive!):

```java
Table<?> table = PUBLIC.getTable("user");
```

And then:

```java
Field<?>[] fields = table.fields();
```

#### Using [`org.jooq.Meta`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Meta.html)

If you don't have generated meta data, you can still look up things from your JDBC connection using [`DSLContext.meta()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta--), from where you can navigate your schemas / tables / etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As correctly stated above, only one addition to further clarify the upcoming users,
PUBLIC is your DefaultSchema, if you have with you, meta generated code.
So,

```
Table<?> table = new DefaultSchema().getTable("user");
```