# How to get column parameters from SQL query (JOOQ)

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a question if it is possible to get parameters from SQL query in JOOQ -java.

I am using something like this:

```
for (Query query: sqlQueries){
    for (Param param: query.getParams().values()) {
         System.out.println("P: "+ param.getName());
    }
}
```

SQL query:

```
...
insert into `filetest` (`Priezvisko`, `Meno`, `Vek`) values ('Kotov', 'Peter', '22');
insert into `filetest` (`Priezvisko`, `Meno`, `Vek`) values ('Alhambra', 'Seat', '33');
insert into `filetest` (`Priezvisko`, `Meno`, `Vek`) values ('F50', 'Ferrari', '100');
```

Will process like that (output):

```
P: Kotov
P: Peter
P: 22
P: Alhambra
P: Seat
P: 33
P: F50
P: Ferrari
P: 100
```

What I also need is to get output with column names like this:

```
P: Priezvisko
P: Meno
P: Vek
P: Kotov
P: Peter
P: 22
... rest
```

Is it possible because I could not figure it out how?
If I can ask is it even possible to get tableName from query ? ('filetest' in our example)

Why I need this is to get those paramaters to create CSV file (SQL -> CSV)
From mentioned SQL create CSV:

```
Meno,Priezvisko,Vek
"Peter","Kotov","22"
"Seat","Alhambra","33"
"Ferrari","F50","100"
```

Comment: Not familiar with JOOQ but a little research point to this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719087/jooq-get-table-and-columns-with-string

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a specific parameter happens to be "linked" to a column in your SQL statement is a rather arbitrary assumption of yours. A simple example that would break your assumption is this statement:

```sql
insert into `filetest` (`Priezvisko`, `Meno`, `Vek`) 
values ((select 'Kotov' from dual where 1 = 0), 'Peter', '22');
```

This statement would now contain 5 parameters:

```sql
P: Kotov -- Relevant
P: 1     -- Irrelevant
P: 0     -- Irrelevant
P: Peter -- Relevant
P: 22    -- Relevant
```

You probably want to work with the generated `FiletestRecord`, which is essentially a `Map<Field<?>, ?>` that can be translated to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements by calling `record.insert()` or `record.update()` or

```java
ctx.insertInto(FILETEST).set(filetestRecord).execute();
```

Comment: What I need is to...get somehow this RED-HIGHLITED "strings" (see picture):
https://imgur.com/a/r1D9yKf

I do not want to execute() or use selects in insert query ... I just want method which process entered SQL query  and get those parameters (inserted values + table columns names + tableName). I am not sure if we understood each other (at least, I did not understand your post, sorry.)

The post I mentioned shows way how to get VALUES (Kotov, Peter,...) but I cannot find way how to get table column names (Meno, priezvisko,vek) and also table name (filetest)

Comment: *"I am not sure if we understood each other"* - Probably not, but you know there are many possible ways to answer a question, once the *intent* is more clear. What you want to do right now is not possible, but perhaps you can re-write your code to make what you want to do possible? I suggest editing your question with details about your motivation (and why e.g. my answer is not viable).